# Python OpenCV open window on top of other applications

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, opencv

When executing an OpenCV python script containing: `cv2.imshow(img)` the resulting window opens behind my terminal window. This is a mild irritation - is there any way to get it to initially open in front / on top?

A number of people have asked questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960968/opencv-window-always-on-top) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417531/opencv-how-to-force-the-image-window-to-appear-on-top-of-other-windows)) about forcing persistent behaviour but this is, I think, simpler.

Platform OS X and OpenCV 2.4.11

Comment: I am using "keyboard mastro " mac app to do this .   First set up a hot key in keyboard mastro as active "python" application in the front with string key "opencvwindowinthefront" . Then in python script ,                                 import os
cmd = """
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "openvwindowinthefront" '
"""
os.system(cmd)

Answer (score 3):

One way to work around this would be to set all windows from OpenCV "frontmost" using AppleScript.

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/osascript", "-e", 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true'])
```

This way, all windows should be brought to the front.

Comment: Works for me. If encounter error: ```21:62: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set process "Python" to true. (-10006)```, try to change ```Python``` to ```python```

Comment: Doesn't work for me even with @MingjiangShi's tip. I get `21:62: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set process "python" to true. (-10006)`

Comment: @Tom I suspect the the python process name is neither Python nor python. Maybe something else like python2 or python27, etc. Try to find out the correct process name in activity monitor and change the script accordingly.

Comment: Works for me after I change `python` to `python3.7`. Find out the process name in "Activity Monitor" app > "Memory" tab.

Comment: another way to find process name in code: (need to install `psutil`):

`pid = os.getpid(); process = psutil.Process(pid); process_name = process.name()`

Comment: Note this does not work on macOS Big Sur 11.1.

Answer (score 2):

I can do what I think you want by adding a single line to the following file in the OpenCV distribution:

```
modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm
```

It is around line 568, and is the single line after the word `SETCHELL` in the code below:

```
    [window setFrameTopLeftPoint:initContentRect.origin];

    [window setFirstContent:YES];

    [window setContentView:[[CVView alloc] init]];

    [window setHasShadow:YES];
    [window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [window useOptimizedDrawing:YES];
    [window setTitle:windowName];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

// SETCHELL - raise window to top of stacking order
[window setLevel:CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey)];

    [window setAutosize:(flags == CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)];

    [windows setValue:window forKey:windowName];

    [localpool drain];
    return [windows count]-1;
}

CV_IMPL int cvWaitKey (int maxWait)
{
```

Comment: Awesome :) Any chance it would be possible to do that with just the python api ?

Comment: @arnaud576875 I think the Python just calls into this Objective-C API anyway on a Mac. So, if you use Python, ultimately this gets called anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Open a `namedWindow` before `imshow`, for instance:

```
cv2.namedWindow('ImageWindowName', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('ImageWindowName',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment if this makes any different.

Comment: This has no effect for me. Window still opens below as before. Anaconda Python 3.5, opencv 3.2.0, Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.5.  Instead, see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775078/4259243.  After opening the window, running `os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "python" to true' ''')` works.

Comment: Note this does not work on macOS Big Sur 11.1.

Comment: Not working for me, macOS 12.3.1