# Python make cv2 window always on top

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have been working on an experiment in cv2 (openCV) where a window displays multiple overlays of the screen and overlaps them. I was wondering how to make the window always on top of other applications. I have checked posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417531/opencv-how-to-force-the-image-window-to-appear-on-top-of-other-windows/45620402) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350240/python-opencv-open-window-on-top-of-other-applications), but since my window is not under the `cv2.namedWindow()` class, I can't find a way that works. My code is below:

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {'top': 40, 'left': 100, 'width': 1200, 'height': 840}

while 'Screen capturing':
    last_time = time.time()+time.time()

    # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
    img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

    # Display the picture
    cv2.imshow('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', img)

    # Press "Q" to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

This is what it should look like:[image: Screengrab]

I don't want to install external libraries.

Any help with making the window topmost would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate (similar questions have been asked many times before). However, the concept of a window being "always on top" would seem to be in conflict with the desire for many windows to stack on top of each other. Do you just want a window to come to the foreground *once* and then other windows can go on top of it?

Comment: A useful thought exercise with this kind of thing is [What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413/)

Comment: I still can't find a solution that works.